# What does き mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

> ぼく の ほう から ちかよる **き** が **なくて**も、きみ に ぶつかられたら、ぼく は こなごな に なってしまう**ん** だから.

What do the words in bold mean? I understand most of the text but can't find the meaning of **き** and the role of **ん** in the sentence.

Comment: Have you tried by looking at the kanji?  And ん is a contraction of the の particle.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: This sentence has no kanji

Comment: あれ？どうして僕のコメントがなくなったんだろう？

Comment: @AeonAkechi 「来」が間違ってるからじゃないですかね・・「気」だし・・

Comment: I see ... I actually thought I'd written 気. It was just a typo. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

the word "ki" here roughly means "intention" or "interest".

き が なくても would thus translate to "even if you don't intend to..."  or "even if it's not your intention to..."

and the ん, as @Breton Loïc stated, is a simplification of の. If you look elsewhere in stackexchange, you will find more detail on its use.

Comment: Is it a verb in -te form?

Comment: you mean because of **なくても**?  The way I learned it in college was similar to this: Verb-ないform (remove い) + **くて(も)** = **even if you don't** Verb...   a common example of this is　 ___しなくてもいい　which is most fluidly translated as "you don't have to ___" ... but you can also think of it more literally as "even if you don't ___, it's fine."

Comment: so, yes, looking at it logically, it's the -te form of the negative form of "aru"